Showing a certain type of function on $\mathbb R ^d$ is Lipschitz?
I want to prove the following:
Assume that $f:\mathbb R ^d \to \mathbb R$ is continuous, convex and $|f(x)|\leq a+b|x|$. Then $f$ is Lipschitz.
I thought it would follow immediately from the assumptions, but I could not get the Lipschitzness no matter what I tried. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Did you try to work out the case $d=1$ and $f$ is twice differentiable? It will get you close to the actual solution.

@MoisheKohan That's a good idea! I'll try that first and see where it gets me!

Any convex function defined on all of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is automatically continuous (in fact, locally Lipschitz continuous, see Theorem 10.4 in Rockafellar for example), so the continuity assumption is redundant.
The key here is that the slope of a convex function $\phi:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, $R(s,t) = {\phi(s)-\phi(t) \over s-t}$ is non decreasing function of $s$ or $t$. Let $\phi(t) = f(y+t(x-y))$ for any $x,y$. Then
$\phi(1)-\phi(0) \le {1 \over t} (\phi(t)-\phi(0))$ for $t \ge 1$. Expanding gives
$f(x)-f(y) \le {1 \over t}(a+b \|y+t(x-y)\| - f(y))$ and letting $t \to \infty$ gives $f(x)-f(y) \le b\|x-y\|$.

It actually suffices to assume a weaker assumption: that $f(x) \le a + b\|x\|$.
Here's an elementary proof:
Suppose we have any line $L$, defined by arbitrary distinct points $x_0, y_0 \in \Bbb{R}^d$. The function $g(\lambda) = f(\lambda x_0 + (1 - \lambda)y_0)$ is a real convex function, hence, for any $n \in \Bbb{Z}$,
$$g(n) \le \frac{g(n+1)+g(n-1)}{2} \implies g(n)-g(n-1) \le g(n+1)-g(n).$$
Thus
$$g(n)-g(n-1) \ge g(n-1) - g(n-2) \ge g(n-2) - g(n-3) \ge \ldots \ge g(1) - g(0).$$
Using a telescoping sum, for $n \ge 1$,
$$g(n) - g(0) = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} [g(i+1) - g(i)] \ge \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} [g(1) - g(0)] = n(g(1) - g(0)) = n(f(x_0) - f(y_0)),$$
hence
$$f(nx_0 + (1 - n)y_0) = g(n) \ge f(y_0) + n(f(x_0) - f(y_0)).$$
Given our assumption, we have
$$f(y_0) + n(f(x_0) - f(y_0)) \le a + b\|nx_0 + (1 - n)y_0\| \le a + b\|y_0\| + nb\|x_0 - y_0\|.$$
Dividing through by $n$,
$$\frac{f(y_0)}{n} + f(x_0) - f(y_0) \le \frac{a + b\|y_0\|}{n} + b\|x_0 - y_0\|.$$
Taking the limit as $n \to \infty$, this yields
$$f(x_0) - f(y_0) \le b\|x_0 - y_0\|.$$
But, we could apply the same logic with $x_0$ and $y_0$ switched, so $f$ is Lipschitz.
Here's a less elementary proof, using Fenchel conjugates:
Suppose we have the weaker inequality $f(x) \le a + b\|x\|$. Recall that $\|x\|$ is the support functional on the unit ball, and hence its Fenchel conjugate is the indicator function on the unit ball, $i_{B[0; 1]}$. Using the standard manipulations of Fenchel conjugates, the conjugate of $a + b\|x\|$ is $-a + i_{B[0;1]}(x/b) = -a + i_{B[0;b]}(x)$. Let the right hand side be $g(x)$. Taking the Fenchel conjugate of both sides (and remembering to reverse the inequality), we obtain
$$f^*(x) \ge i_{B[0; b]}(x) - a.$$
But, the right hand side is $\infty$ for $x \notin B[0; b]$, meaning that the Fenchel conjugate has bounded domain (bounded by $b$). This implies $f$ has Lipschitz, with Lipschitz constant at most $b$ (the max formula is helpful to show this).
